# Java. Communicate two peer-to-peer applications

Tags: java, rmi

I am studying communications in Java using RMI and in all the references that I find there is a client that makes calls to remote methods in a server.
That is, all communications are initiated by the client.

If I wanted two computers to communicate as equals, would it be right for each of them to implement a remote object? That is, the two applications would play the role of client and server.

Thank you

Comment: I'm with Maciej on this one, RMI is more for explicitly calling external code on a server to invoke a method. If you really want peer-to-peer networking, you should use sockets and pass packets of data back and forth.

Comment: 'If I wanted two computers to communicate as equals, would it be right for each of them to implement a remote object?': Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating desktop application, you could use sockets for communications between many computers.

A **socket** is one end-point of a two-way communication link between two or more programs running on the network. Socket classes are used to represent the connection between a client program and a server program. [More.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html)

[Example code for server/client applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

You should know that you will need a bit of knowledge about concurrency and networking to create good communication between many computers. Creating simple server/client applications is very good way to achieve it :)

Please remember that client will always need **IP:PORT** address to connect to server.